# DDL for composite primary key

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables with a Many-to-Many relationship with each other.

```
Profile(profile_id, profile_name, weight, hobbies, height, gender, dating_geo_range, dating_age_range, hair_colour, photo, location)
```

PK is profile_id

```
Customer (id, rating, last_active_date_time, subscription_type)
```

PK is id

So their relationship schema will contain both their primary,

```
ProfileCreated(id, profile_id, last_mod_date, creation_date)
```

PK is (id, profile_id)

May I know whether my DDL for the ProfileCreated is correct?

```
Create table profileCreated(
    id int NOT NULL REFERENCES person(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    profile_id int NOT NULL REFERENCES profile(profile_id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    last_mod_date datetime NOT NULL,
    creation_date datetime DEFAULT GETDATE(),
    PRIMARY KEY (id, profile_id)
)
```

Comment: Not really clear what the question is here but as you have this coded if the ProfileCreated row is deleted it will delete the Person and the Profile. Not sure that is really what you want.

Comment: Your DDL looks like a *valid* expression of what you describe.  Whether it's in fact what you want is a different question.  Did you try it?  Also @SeanLange appears to be mixed up.  An `ON DELETE` clause specifies what to do to the constrained row when the referenced row is deleted, not the other way around.  Thus, with your code, if the person or profile referenced by a given `profileCreated` row is deleted then that `profileCreated` row will be deleted, too.

Comment: @JohnBollinger right you are. It was totally unformatted when I posted my comment and I didn't notice it was the actual ddl for the profileCreated table. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I'm just wondering whether this is a valid expression. Because I've seen some whereby they treat id and profile_id as FK, such as
FOREIGN KEY profile_id int NOT NULL REFERENCES person(id) ...
FOREIGN KEY id int NOT NULL REFERENCES profile(profile_id)...

Is there any difference between this and the DDL shown in the question?

Comment: @LeonBrain, your DDL looks valid to me for SQL Server.  If I understand you correctly, you're asking whether it is valid to omit the keywords `FOREIGN KEY` in your FK constraints, as you do.  [The docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979.aspx) say they are optional.